# Reading a text file with more strings on a line and scanner doesn't notice spaces

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently trying to scan through text from a data file and it doesnt recognize the space so it counts it as 2 strings when printed.

```
  while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String id = scanner.next();
        String species = scanner.next();
        String name = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(id + "\t" + species + "\t" + name);
        lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

That's the code I have and on the line with the space inbetween the species, it prints out the second half of the species and therefore doesn't add the name on the end.

Comment: What is the separator between species and name in input file?

Comment: There is no separator, what should it be if there should be one

Comment: next() scans string before next delimiter (whitespace by default, can be set in Scanner constructor), nextLine() - before line break. I don't get, what is the input format?

Comment: You should give a short sample of the data file you're trying to parse. Otherwise it'll be very difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Bird Golden Eagle Charlie... That's one line of the file that I need help with, I need Golden Eagle to be 1 string but the scanner classes it as 2 so the name is Eagle and therefore doesnt output Charlie

Comment: So, how you think program should guess, witch of spaces is delimiter, and witch is part of token? I mean, why not to treat it as Golden with name 'Eagle Charlie'? Such format can't be parsed definitely